# C language library equivalent to Java ScheduledExecutorService?

Tags: c

I want a thread pool that will allow jobs to be scheduled after a specific delay or at an absolute time, for which I would use `ScheduledExecutorService` in Java.  Is anybody familiar with a C library providing equivalent functionality?  Actually, I want something with even more features than provided by Java: I want new threads to be created as necessary instead of being chosen from a fixed-size pool, which would be the equivalent of `java.util.concurrent.Executors` implementing something like a `newCachedScheduledThreadPool()` method.  Seems like I want a lot, is it Christmas yet?

Answer (score 1):

You might try Glib for thread pools:

http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-Thread-Pools.html

I know this doesn't quite give you the equivalent of **ScheduledExecutorService**, but it seems it should be relatively easy to write some wrapper code which could implement the scheduling part.